# Optimising WordPress query speed by grouping metadata

Tags: database, wordpress, optimization, metadata

I am building an eCommerce site and I have about 10 different custom post types. For each custom post type, I have about 20 custom fields (with a single meta_value assigned to each meta_key).

What I was thinking about doing is grouping all 20 custom fields into a single custom field so that I'll have 20 meta_values (array) assigned to a single meta_key. This would essentially reduce the number of rows inside the database table from 20 rows down to a single row for each custom post type.

For example, let's say I have post type "book".
Currently my post_meta table for this post type might look like this:

```
meta_key   | meta_value
_________________________
chapters   |     5
_________________________
paragraphs |    10
_________________________
author     | john_smith
_________________________
price      |     19
_________________________
```

If I convert it to this:

```
meta_key    | meta_value
____________________________
book_detail | [chapters:5 ,paragraphs:10, author:john_smith, price:19]
____________________________
```

Would doing something like this optimize WordPress query speed or would I just be wasting time?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? and how meta_key came to be `book_detail`?

Comment: I am using mariadb. I would manually re-write the php code to accommodate the change.

Comment: how did value `book_detail` came in meta_key column? Is it constant?

Comment: I would manually book_detail by doing update_post_meta(1, 'book_detail' , array("chapter"=>5,"paragraphs"=>10,"author"=>"john_smith","price"=>19). Essentially I would be manually deleting all the meta_keys in the current table and converting it into the "optimised?" meta_key

Comment: I didn't understand what you just said. Is there another column in the table you posted as example above? 'post_type' maybe?

Comment: Yes there are two other colums (meta_id and post_id) but they are not important. My question is: which of the two example tables would be faster to query/ run faster?

Comment: Answer this: would you **ever** need to query a specific aspect of a post for e.g. only `chapters`? Is the data always used at once?

Comment: No, most of the time I would need only a specific aspect, e.g. chapter or price

Comment: But I am worried table would get too big e.g millions of rows, therefore queries would become very slow. Am I wrong?

Comment: But you are not going to query all of them at once. To speed up the querying of required rows, appropriate indexes can be used.

Comment: To be honest I have very little knowledge of databases/queries. Would you mind explaining " appropriate indexes can be used". Thank you so much

Comment: Appropriate meaning *creating indexes on relevant column i.e. the ones that will be frequently filtered or used in joins.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables should be kept as normalized as possible. Storing the CSV or any delimited values is not recommended.

Also, in case you need to query a specific aspect of a post such as only `chapters`, then normalized data comes handy where you just need to put a simple predicate:

```
where metakey = 'chapters';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, but I was not looking for any code. What I need to know is if I convert the first table to the second table speed up the wordpress query?

Comment: Your current structure is better.  DO NOT DENORMALIZE the data.

Comment: Thank you, that's the answer I was looking for.